# Polynomial in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have an exam on thursday about Functional programming and I’m pretty sure that I will have to do a TAD with Polynomials. I’m adding polynomials for the moment like this:

```
type Pol = [(Int,Int)] 

suma :: Pol -> Pol -> Pol
suma [] ys = ys
suma xs [] = xs
suma ((c1,g1):xs) ((c2,g2):ys)
    | g1 == g2  = ((c1+c2,g1):(suma xs ys))
    | g1 > g2 = ((c1,g1):(suma xs ((c2,g2):ys)))
    | g1 < g2 = ((c2,g2):(suma ((c1,g1):xs) ys))
```

It perfectly works but the teacher doesn’t like. She prefers to do it with:

```
data Pol = P [(Int,Int)] deriving Show
```

At the beginning, I though it would be easy to change the structure but it’s not as I’m getting a lot of trouble in the compilation. Can anyone help me please? I tried this way but it doesn’t work:

```
data Pol = P [(Int,Int)] deriving Show

suma :: Pol -> Pol -> Pol
suma (P []) (P ys) = P ys
suma (P xs) (P []) = P xs
suma (P ((c1,g1):xs)) (P ((c2,g2):ys))
    | g1 == g2  = P ((c1+c2,g1):suma (P xs) (P ys))
    | g1 > g2   = P ((c1,g1):(suma (P xs) (P ((c2,g2):ys))))
    | g1 < g2   = P ((c2,g2):(suma (P ((c1,g1):xs)) (P ys)))
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR file:.\Febrero 2011.hs:7 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : P (c1 + c2,g1) : suma (P xs) (P ys)
*** Term           : suma (P xs) (P ys)
*** Type           : Pol
*** Does not match : [a]
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Usually if the compilation doesn't work, the compiler prints messages that can be useful for solving the problem.

Comment: As an aside, I would use `newtype` instead of `data` to avoid the extra indirection.

Answer (score 3):

If something doesn't work, please explain why in the question.  If there are compiler errors, please post them.

In this case, the problem is a type error in the last branches of `suma`.  Look at

```
suma (P ((c1,g1):xs)) (P ((c2,g2):ys))
    | g1 == g2  = P ((c1+c2,g1):suma (P xs) (P ys))
```

In `P ((c1+c2,g1):suma (P xs) (P ys))`, you're trying to create a list of type `[(Int,Int)]` with

```
(c1+c2,g1):suma (P xs) (P ys)
```

You're trying to construct a list with the head at type `(Int,Int)`, but the tail at type `Pol` (the result type of `suma`).  The other cases have similar errors.

Comment: Ok, you´re rigth. This is my firt question so I didn´t know how to ask properly. I will write the error on the question. Anyway, is there any way to make it work as I want?, I mean to create a list of [(Int,Int)]. Thank you!!

Comment: It's possible, however for schoolwork-related questions, it's common practice for responders to attempt to direct you to the answer rather than just "giving the codez".  You'll need to remove the `P` constructor from the interior list.  If you create an auxiliary function with type `Pol -> [(Int,Int)]` you can use that function to unwrap the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Make suma to work on List such that:

```
suma :: [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
suma [] ys = ys
suma xs [] = xs
suma ((c1,g1):xs) ((c2,g2):ys)
    | g1 == g2  = ((c1+c2,g1):(suma xs ys))
    | g1 > g2 = ((c1,g1):(suma xs ((c2,g2):ys)))
    | g1 < g2 = ((c2,g2):(suma ((c1,g1):xs) ys))
```

Then Sum for Pol can be defined as:

```
sumPol :: Pol -> Pol -> Pol
sumPol (P a) (P b) = P (suma a b)
```

In case you want to be more stylish or monadic :) then you can make Pol a monad and use a do notation to do the stuff

Comment: It looks good and much easier but I don´t know if my teacher will like that much. I will use this way if I can´t get to do it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's consider your original code

```
type Pol = [(Int,Int)] 

suma :: Pol -> Pol -> Pol
suma [] ys = ys
suma xs [] = xs
suma ((c1,g1):xs) ((c2,g2):ys)
    | g1 == g2  = ((c1+c2,g1):(suma xs ys))
    | g1 > g2 = ((c1,g1):(suma xs ((c2,g2):ys)))
    | g1 < g2 = ((c2,g2):(suma ((c1,g1):xs) ys))
```

If you do:

```
let p1 = [(5,0),(1,1),(7,2)]::Pol
let p2 = [(1,2),(3,1),(2,0)]::Pol
```

then you get:

```
suma p1 p2
[(1,2),(3,1),(7,0),(1,1),(7,2)]
```

This is not "wrong", but it's not what one may expect out of summing two polynomials: you may want to get the result in its simplified form:

```
[(7,0),(4,1),(8,2)]
```

One more comment: have you learned about Haskell [record syntax](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax)? I think it can simplify your work and make things cleared. Here's a hint:

```
data Term = Term { coeff :: Int,
                   expnt :: Int
                 } deriving Show

data Pol = Pol { terms :: [Term] } deriving Show
```

With that, summing two polynomials without simplifying the result is as simple as ... concatenating their terms :) ... and everything is showable:

```
Main> let p1 = Pol [Term 5 0, Term 1 1, Term 7 2]
Main> p1
Pol {terms = [Term {coeff = 5, expnt = 0},Term {coeff = 1, expnt = 1},Term {coeff = 7, expnt = 2}]}
Main> let p2 = Pol [Term 1 2, Term 3 1, Term 2 0]
Main> p2
Pol {terms = [Term {coeff = 1, expnt = 2},Term {coeff = 3, expnt = 1},Term {coeff = 2, expnt = 0}]}
Main> let p3 = sumpol p1 p2
Main> p3
Pol {terms = [Term {coeff = 5, expnt = 0},Term {coeff = 1, expnt = 1},Term {coeff = 7, expnt = 2},Term {coeff = 1, expnt = 2},Term {coeff = 3, expnt = 1},Term {coeff = 2, expnt = 0}]}
```

Simplification of a polynomial is a little trickier, but a good exercise.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. The thing is that this is just to prepare an exam so I won´t have further relation with Haskell so I don´t need go get deeper. Greetings from Spain!!